# Restart webapplication from the point where it was stopped due to server crash

Tags: java

We have implemented one web-application as a scheduler which sends email campaigns for the configured mailing lists. It processes contacts one by one. how can I recover the crashing point to restart my campaign process from where it was stopped.

Ex: I have configured 100 `emailIds` to the mailing list.
after processing 50 `emailIds`, the server shuts down or crash occurred.
when I restart the server, again it starts from 1st `emailId` instead of 51st `emailId`.

We have tried some solutions based on our application logic but that created performance issues. Is there any common solution that can be handled at the server level?
Can u please suggest some solution?

Comment: which scheduler are you using currently ?

Comment: The best way it's track sent ids. Or current id to keep sending start with it.

Comment: Hi triclosan,Yes tracking sent Ids are the best way, but we are creating sent Ids for all the emails id before the campaign process starts due to business requirement.

Comment: try to maintain state in database.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can save the number to a file and update it after each processed mail and read it on start-up. But what you really need to ask yourself is why the server is crashing..

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the email IDs in the text file and read one by one. Within my knowledge it's best approach. Otherwise, store it in to the XML file and read that. If you are using XML parser it doesn't have the heavy weight and your server might not be hanged.